# Is it possible to open an application from a ".chm" file

Tags: windows-7, chm

I want to open an application(Windows 7 Desktop APP) from a .chm file, is it possible as i want the application to get invoked for showing demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not recommended - try to show the main features by e.g. an Powerpoint presentation and hold your application minimized in the task bar to show quickly.

- Usually, the application calls its help and not vice versa.
- This would be a huge security breach.

If you are not to teach you may put it in a batch:

```
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Help-Info\" KIT.exe
```

make a HTML window.open like:

```
<input type="button" value="Launch Batch for starting KIT.exe" onclick="window.open('file:///D:/_temp/HTMLHelp_Examples/batch-calling-exe.bat')" />
```

and compile both into your CHM and hold all files local and not on a network share.

You maybe warned again - think about a `format x:` in the batch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it solves my purpose. I am opening a demo project from the chm file and this is a usual scenario not sure why you are saying not recommended.